# Linked list only deletes in debug, but not in building

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Here is a simple implementation of a singly-linked list with `create()`,`addnode()` and `destroy()` functions. After I called the destroy function, I printed `head->val`, which should give a segmentation fault, as the memory is freed. However, this only happens in debug mode. If I build and run, the program has no issue printing the head and even the entire list.

Any ideas on why debugging and building give different outcomes?
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

typedef struct sllist{
    int val;
    struct sllist* next;
}
sllnode;

sllnode* create(int value)
{
    sllnode* p =(sllnode*) malloc(sizeof(sllnode));
    if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    p->val=value;
    p->next=NULL;
    return p;
}

sllnode* addnode(sllnode* head, int value)
{
    sllnode* p =(sllnode*) malloc(sizeof(sllnode));
    if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    p->val=value;
    p->next=head;
    return p;
}

void destroy(sllnode* head){
    if(head == NULL)
        return;
    destroy(head->next);
    free(head);
}

int main()
{
    sllnode* head = create(6);
    for(int i=1;i<=5;++i)
    {
        head=addnode(head,i+1);
    }
    sllnode* p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->val;
        p=p->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<head<<"\n";
    destroy(head);
    cout<<head->val;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++, then use C++ features (`new`, `unique_ptr`, etc.). If you're using C, then don't use `iostream` :/ Printing something that has been `free`d is UB. Compilers can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: Welcome to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), a mysterious land where ANYTHING can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I called the destroy function, I printed head->val, which should give a segmentation fault, as the memory is freed.

You are mistaken: accessing freed memory *almost never* results in a segmentation fault.

> why debugging and building give different outcomes?

Debugging allocators often overwrite freed memory with an easily recognizable pattern, such as `0xCDCDCDCDCD...` or `0xDEADBEEF...`. Reading such memory *still* does not result in a segmentation fault, but *dereferencing a pointer* residing in freed memory does (that's the purpose of overwriting freed memory).